# Sharing a screenshot in Android to social media with minimal permissions

Tags: android, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x, android-permissions

Can you use Intent ACTON_SEND to share a screenshot without saving it to the external storage (as in getExternalStorageDirectory()) but rather by saving it to wherever getFilesDir() points you? Or even better - without saving the screenshot at all.

Or is there a better way altogether?

I'm trying to add screenshot sharing to a cocos2d-x game.
I would like to minimize the permissions the game needs to be given and it should work both with, and without and SD card being available.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you use Intent ACTON_SEND to share a screenshot... by saving it to wherever getFilesDir() points you?

You can use `FileProvider` to serve files from `getFilesDir()` to third parties. You would use a `content:` `Uri`, obtained from `FileProvider`, in `EXTRA_STREAM` of your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`.

> Or even better - without saving the screenshot at all.

That gets a bit dicey. There's nothing stopping you from creating your own `ContentProvider` that serves a PNG from your heap space in response to `openFile()`. However, if your process winds up being terminated before the other app is done streaming in the PNG, then you're in trouble.

> without and SD card being available

External storage is not removable on most Android devices.